# Remove top right histogram text in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How can I remove what appears on the top right corner of a histogram generated with gnuplot?
My plot looks like this one http://old.nabble.com/file/p30162131/Figure%2B0.jpg

I don't want the weird text that appears at the top right corner to appear.

Answer (score 3):

Ok the problem was that I didn't know what the name of that area in a graph is. I asked a person and since the name is **key** the solution was to do:

```
unset key
```